# creating accompanying slides for bookdown project

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown, beamer

In Rstudio, I create a new project and select book project using `bookdown`.  The built in example runs perfectly as expected and i can compile 4 books - gitbook, html, epub, and pdf.  Great.

The next obvious step is to want to have slides at the same time, very much in line with what the `beamer package` does, allowing for both `beamer mode` and `article mode`.  Therefore, I tried to add another output in the _`output.yml` code:  `bookdown::pdf_document2`.  In line with the documentation, I know I should be able to define the `base_format` to use `rmarkdown::beamer`,  [The package author told me I was almost right, see this link for the discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/485).
Punchline:  I use this amended `_output.yml` for the default project:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
bookdown::pdf_document2:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
```

which is exactly the suggestion XieYihui kindly made.  However, I am getting a compile fail, when the pdf_book needs to be built:

```
Output created: _book/index.html
Error in base_format(toc = toc, number_sections = number_sections, fig_caption = fig_caption,  : 
  unused argument (number_sections = number_sections)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I am lost - I spent hours looking for a solution without success.  Could anyone kindly help me?  I am so sorry i have not been able to figure this one out.  XieYiHui has been incredibly supportive and his comments suggest this is the right venue for such questions.  Many thanks. thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was due to the fact that `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation()` does not have the argument `number_sections` (you cannot number sections in beamer; at least Pandoc doesn't seem to support it).

To get around this issue, you may use the following hack, which basically defines a base format that throws away the `number_sections` argument:

````
---
title: "Using bookdown with Beamer"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: "function(..., number_sections) rmarkdown::beamer_presentation(...)"
    number_sections: false
---

## Plot

See Figure \@ref(fig:foo).

```{r, foo, fig.cap='Hi there', fig.height=4}
plot(1:10)
```
````

Comment: This works - thank you so much!  I just need to understand how to change the file name - because `bookdown::pdf_book` and `bookdown::pdf_document2` output to the same file - which gets therefore overwritten!  I know how to change filenames and locations for all files at once using `_bookdown.yml`, but I do not know how to do it for individual files....  i will search more online, but did not see anything so far - do I need to post another question for this if I cannot find anything? many thanks, thomas

Comment: could not find an answer anywhere about how to customize the individual book filenames... apologies.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot customize the output filename through any YAML options.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response.  Really appreciated.  There is no way to throw in some pandoc command?  So you are saying that if I want to compile all books at once, I am doomed to overwrite the pdf built with the first `bookdown::pdf_book` when i run the second `bookdown::pdf_document2`?? Many thanks, thomas

Comment: So... i guess the only option if so would be to hope for a future version of _bookdown_ to allow for some extra options such as `bookdown::slides` for instance? ;-p

Comment: Fyi... I tried to pass `"-o", "FILE.pdf"` and variations to pandoc, but that did not seem to work.