# Impossible to cross-referring figures and tables with `beamer_presentation` option in `knitr`

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, beamer

## Why does `\@ref()` notation fail to operate with beamer-presentation?

The following question may remind you some questions on cross-reference when knitting PDF document, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861041/knitr-rmarkdown-latex-how-to-cross-reference-figures-and-tables), but the methods introduced in the answers have not help me when I make beamer-presentations.

Now I'm confused because `\@ref(fig:label-to-refer-figure)` and `\@ref(tab:label-to-refer-table)` notation to refer a figure/table does not work when I am knitting an `.Rmd` file with the option `output: beamer_presentation`. As shown in the following images, the raw codes for the cross-reference appear on the outputted PDF file and I cannot refer the figure/table number. Although the citations go well even in the listed environment as well as in plain text field, cross-reference for figure/table number does not properly take effect.

[image]

[image]

## My environment

- R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
- knitr_1.20
- rmarkdown_1.10
- **RStudio v1.2.1206** (Preview Version) <- I prefer this for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956273/10215301)

## MWEs

The MWE I post here is created from the following sources: `test-beamer.Rmd` and `myref.bib`.

### `test-beamer.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Test"
subtitle: |
  | subtitle,
  | with a line break
author: |
  | CLR
  | Rafael
institute: |
  | Now I'm here,
  | Now I'm there
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y/%b/%d')`" #English
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: lualatex
    theme: "AnnArbor"
    colortheme: "dolphin"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    toc: true
    #toc_depth: 3
    #number_sections: TRUE
    fig_caption: TRUE
    dev: cairo_pdf
    #extra_dependencies: subfig
    citation_package: natbib
    slide_level: 2 
bibliography: bibs/myref.bib
biblio-style: apa
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## The only thing

With Table \@ref(tab:under-pressure-table), @test-master shows that Figure \@ref(fig:under-pressure) depicts...

## Slide with Bullets in which I want to refer a figure

- \@ref(fig:under-pressure)
- @test-master
- \@ref(tab:under-pressure-table)

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r under-pressure, fig.cap='Under Pressure', fig.pos='h', out.width="0.75\\textwidth"}
plot(pressure)
```

## Slide with Table

```{r under-pressure-table, caption = "This is a table"}
knitr::kable(pressure)
```

## More extraordinary

With Table \@ref(tab:under-pressure-table), @test-master shows that Figure \@ref(fig:under-pressure) depicts...
````

EDIT: I added `fig.cap='Under Pressure', fig.pos='h', out.width="0.75\\textwidth"` to the figure chunk, and `caption = "This is a table"` to the `knitr::kable()`. Without these codes, neither the caption nor table/figure numbers appear at all... However, the problem persists even after giving them to the entire `.Rmd` file, unless you carry out @Yihui's answer.

### `myref.bib`

```
@master{test-master,
author = {Freddie Mercury and Brian May and John Deacon and Roger Taylor},
title = {Bohemian {R}hapsody: {W}e are the champions},
school = {{Queen}},
year = {2018},
address = {London}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\@ref()` notation is a feature of **bookdown** only. To port this feature to general R Markdown documents, you may set the `base_format` option of a certain **bookdown** output format, e.g.,

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
```

See [Section 3.4 of the **bookdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html) for details.

The completed yaml section which suits for the MWE of this question may be like this:

```
---
title: "Test"
subtitle: |
  | subtitle,
  | with a line break
author: |
  | CLR
  | Rafael
institute: |
  | Now I'm here,
  | Now I'm there
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y/%b/%d')`" #English
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: "function(..., number_sections) rmarkdown::beamer_presentation(...)"
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: lualatex
    theme: "AnnArbor"
    colortheme: "dolphin"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    toc: true
    fig_caption: TRUE
    dev: cairo_pdf
    #extra_dependencies: subfig
    citation_package: natbib
    slide_level: 2     
bibliography: bibs/myref.bib
biblio-style: apa
always_allow_html: yes
---
```

Comment: As you answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431382/10215301) before, we need to write `base_format: "function(..., number_sections) rmarkdown::beamer_presentation(...)"` instead of `base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation` to avoid the error message described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52429949/10215301). Moreover, the Boolean variables in `number_sections` after the `base_format` section does not affect the result: we can get the final pdf output no matter which we specify, `true` or `false`,  in `number_sections`.

Comment: @Yihui: how would the command read to repeat the same for ioslides, i.e. to include bookdown referencing in slides generated with ioslides? Many thanks!