# Using bookdown commands in ioslides presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown, ioslides

Using `bookdown` commands in an R markdown presentation with [output format "beamer" works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041552/impossible-to-cross-referring-figures-and-tables-with-beamer-presentation-opti) (see also [this SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429949/creating-accompanying-slides-for-bookdown-project/52431382#52431382)).
In the YAML header, one simply has to change from

```
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
```

to

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
```

However, how to use `bookdown` commands in an R markdown presentation with output format "ioslides"

MWE:

````
---
title: "ioslides_presentation with bookdown commands"
output:
  ioslides_presentation: default
  # Not working:
  # bookdown::pdf_book:
    # base_format: rmarkdown::ioslides_presentation
---

# Set of slides

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with bookdown cross references
- Figure: \@ref(fig:plot)
- Table: \@ref(tab:table)
- Slide without ref: \@ref(some-slide)
- Slide with ref: \@ref(slide-with-ref)

## Slide with Plot
```{r plot, fig.cap='Plot caption'}
plot(pressure)
```

## Slide with Table
```{r table}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:3]),
             caption = "Table caption")
```

## Some Slide
Some text

## Another Slide {#slide-with-ref}
Some more text
````