# bookdown: customize the output filename

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

This is a follow up to an earlier question I asked here:  [creating accompanying slides for bookdown project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429949/creating-accompanying-slides-for-bookdown-project)
`Bookdown` allows compiling the file to various format, including multiple `pdf`.  The issue is therefore to give the output different names.  If not, the second `pdf` compile overwrites the first one!

In the comments to my earlier question, I wrote:  "I just need to understand how to change the file name - because `bookdown::pdf_book` and `bookdown::pdf_document2` output to the same file - which gets therefore overwritten! I know how to change filenames and locations for all files at once using `_bookdown.yml`, but I do not know how to do it for individual files.... i will search more online, but did not see anything so far - do I need to post another question for this if I cannot find anything?"
YiHui Xie responded:  "Unfortunately you cannot customize the output filename through any `YAML` options"
I suggested: "i guess the only option if so would be to hope for a future version of `bookdown` to allow for some extra options such as `bookdown::slides` for instance?"
and added "I tried to pass `"-o", "FILE.pdf"` and variations to `pandoc`, but that did not seem to work"
Throwing this did not work either:   `pandoc_args: [ "--output", "slides.pdf" ]`
but I do not think anyone noticed this question anymore and therefore, I am throwing this as an actual question, please, with the hope of finding a solution!  many thanks in advance.  thomas

Comment: I also would love such an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who might be interested in an answer, I asked the question directly on ([GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/737)), and the package author Xie YiHui kindly responded:

> The only way at the moment is to render (bookdown::render_book()) to
>   the default output filename, rename it (file.rename()), then render
>   the next output format, and also rename the output file to your
>   desired filename. This process could be automated via an R script. I
>   don't have time for a more detailed answer. Sorry.