# Having a beamer_presentation and a pdf_book in the same Bookdown project

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, beamer

In my Bookdown project, I have both a `bookdown::pdf_book` and a `beamer_presentation` specificed in the `_output.yml`. (Why? Here is [an example](https://github.com/tamas-ferenci/FerenciTamas_ValszamEsStatAlapvonalai), and here is [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885889/embedding-a-beamer-presentation-in-a-regular-document-with-rmarkdown/59013249#59013249).)

The problem is that `pdf_book` seems to respect the `output_dir` specified in `_bookdown.yml`, but not the `beamer_presentation`. Thus, when hitting the `Build Book` button, the presentation won't get into the `docs` directory, it'll appear in the base directory.

Is there any way to make `beamer_presentation` respect the `output_dir` specification?

(Also, it'll mean that something has to be done with the filenames, as by default the the names would be the same.)

EDIT: I realized that using `bookdown::beamer_presentation2` instead of `beamer_presentation` will solve the problem, as it'll respect the `output_dir`. But I'd call it a partial answer, as my fears in the last sentence realized: this will simply overwrite the `pdf_book` (as they'll indeed have the same name), so it is still not really working...

Comment: Doesn't this look like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639760/bookdown-customize-the-output-filename ?

Comment: @tchevrier The original question (how to respect `output_dir`) was not a duplicate, but the later question in "EDIT" is. I'm okay if anyone wants to vote to close this post as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, its really a "half-duplicate" now, thanks @tchevrier for mentioning that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `bookdown::beamer_presentation2`, which will respect the `output_dir` setting in `_bookdown.yml`.

Regarding to your second problem (two formats having the same output filename), there isn't a nice solution at the moment if you only want to click the Knit button in RStudio---you have to call `rmarkdown::render()` and specify the output filename in the call, e.g.,

```r
rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd', 'bookdown::pdf_book', output_file = 'book.pdf')
rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd', 'bookdown::beamer_presentation2', output_file = 'beamer.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Do you have any prediction whether this feature (i.e. that the output file's name can be specified in `_bookdown.yml`, so that Render button will be sufficient) will ever be implemented? I totally understand that there is no timeline you can promise, just an approximation (I have no idea how complicated this would be).

Comment: again, this solution looks like a duplicate of the one you provided for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639760/bookdown-customize-the-output-filename ? I also raised this issue in your related post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885889/embedding-a-beamer-presentation-in-a-regular-document-with-rmarkdown/60552065#60552065  +1 would be nice feature to have...

Comment: @tchevrier Thanks for the reminder! I have totally forgotten it, but will definitely reconsider it in the future since the [Github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/737) is still open.

Comment: Now you know why we all love you so much! :-)

Comment: Thank you both! I am really happy that it has an open issue on Github, I already subscribed to its notification. Hope it'll be resolved one day :) Thanks again!

Comment: and if you could somehow help to get pandoc to revert from the idiotic behavior of slapping non-slide content onto a slide - that would be really much appreciated. At this time, it's just me alone fighting against windmills... Don Quichotte style.