# Pandoc #4317 forces content under title slides to be included in a frame in pandoc > 2.7

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, beamer

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429949/creating-accompanying-slides-for-bookdown-project) I explained my goal: creating accompanying slides for a bookdown project. I chose the `Beamer` format for the slides and was happy.

However, upgrading to `Pandoc 2.7` onwards (>2.6) caused my project to produce undesired slides. Specifically, any previously ignored content is now thrown into an ad-hoc slide!  I find this behavior quite odd, as my understanding was that choosing `slide_level: 3` meant `###` was needed to create a slide!

After insane amount of hours, I found what caused the issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4317, leading to [this change](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/5990f14ad497999141a5b975651f83d751ec421f).

I have tried so many things, impossible to list them all. At the end of the day, no matter what I tried, my content ends up in a slide!!  I thought at least

````
```{=beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\title[Lecture1]{\CourseName{} \newline \, Lecture 1}
\date{\DayOne{}}
}
```
````

would escape from being thrown in a slide: nope.

Here is the actual code attempt in my `.rmd` file:

```
`r if (out_type=="beamer") "##\n"`
```

````
```{=beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\title[Lecture1]{\CourseName{} \newline \, Lecture 1}
\date{\DayOne{}}
}
```
````

leads to the following `.tex` file:

```
\hypertarget{section-1}{%
\subsection{}\label{section-1}}

\begin{frame}{}

\mode<presentation>
{
\title[Lecture1]{\CourseName{} \newline \, Lecture 1}
\date{\DayOne{}}
}

\end{frame}
```

and you can see the `\mode<presentation>` is now slapped onto a slide instead of doing its previous job...

Until `pandoc 2.7`, with my `\mode` command above, i was able to change the title slide for each chapter (syllaybus -> lecture 1 -> lecture 2 -> etc...). Now, I can no longer achieve this, instead, I am getting an undesired, unrequested slide - I guess I am left with rolling back to `pandoc 2.6`?

I am sure there is a better way and I sincerely apologize for having failed to find it. Much appreciated any help I can get with this - it's been a few months now :-(

Comment: As requested by John MacFarlane, I posted this issue [here, on the pandoc-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/joqekZQRpq8). He added a summary of the issue which might be useful to anyone kindly willing to help. Many thanks

Comment: Apparently I am being bitten by the same issue! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630390/add-a-beamer-note-to-a-section-slide-using-pandoc-and-markdown